# Disable a HyperLink from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, webforms

In my project I need to disable a hyperlink based on some condition. So how can I do this from code behind using C#?

Comment: Im assuming you mean a client-side anchor tag? If that's the case, you can't. You'll have to do it with javascript. (or make the anchor tag a server-side asp.net control)

Comment: Also, is this a WebForms based or an MVC based application?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in your aspx, add runat="server" attribute to the tag:

```
<a id="myHyperLink" runat="server">...</a>
```

in Page_load method:

```
if( condition )
    myHyperLink.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. 'Enabled' isn't recognised server-side as a property of an <a> tag. Had to use an <asp:hyperlink> control. Can't understand how it worked for anyone else.

Comment: doesnt work for me as wll. Anyone with a better way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

in your aspx, add runat="server" and id attribute to the tag:

in Page_load method:
if(condition)
  ep_sms.HRef = "#";

Answer (score 0):

`myHyperLink.Enabled = false;` does not work with `<a>` links

Instead use `aria-disabled="true"`

In your method add this:

```
myHyperLink.Attributes.Add("aria-disabled", "true");
```

links:

[https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/articles/disable-elements/#:~:text=It%20is%20still%20possible%20to,is%20indicated%20as%20being%20disabled](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/articles/disable-elements/#:%7E:text=It%20is%20still%20possible%20to,is%20indicated%20as%20being%20disabled)

[How to add custom attributes to ASP.NET controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858742/how-to-add-custom-attributes-to-asp-net-controls)